# Use of ? in named groups in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to search - using regular expressions - for parts of a string that might be present or absent. E.g. 'I am born in 2000 in Holland', 'I am born in 2000' or 'I am born in Holland'. The use of the question mark puzzles me. In the example I use two named groups. I don't understand why using a question mark in both named groups does not give my expected result. 
Question marks for both named groups result in

```
>>> line = 'I am born in 2000 in Holland'
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))?', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'year': None, 'country': None}
```

I expected that both named groups would give the searched content of the line. I can't understand why regular expressions gave the result None for both named groups.

With deleting one question mark after the first named group or after the second one gives the expected result.

```
>>> line = 'I am born in 2000 in Holland'
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))?', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'year': '2000', 'country': 'Holland'}
```

and

```
>>> line = 'I am born in 2000 in Holland'
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'year': '2000', 'country': 'Holland'}
```

In the string with only one field use of the expression with two question marks the result is in fact the same as above:

```
>>> line = 'I am born in 2000'
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))?', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'year': None, 'country': None}
```

With only one question mark the results are as expected:

```
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

and:

```
>>> line = 'I am born in 2000'
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))?', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'year': '2000', 'country': None}
```

Please who can tell me were my knowledge of Python on regular expressions is deficient.

Comment: I'm not sure that `[A-z]` will work as you expect it to. In any case, a site like https://regex101.com/ help a lot to understand what's actually happening in your regex, and tweaking and testing it.

Comment: I found out that the asterix instead of the questionmark will do the job in a correct way. Thanx for reading this post.

Comment: Asterisk `*` show example. Problem is typical overlapping of terms and confluence of requirements.    You want to match alpha's and space in beginning while having optional alpha's and space at the end. The left side always wins unless it's tamed.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, everything after `[A-Za-z ]+` is optional. The evaluator knows this, so it doesn't bother. It stops when it has matched (or is unable to match) `[A-Za-z ]+`. If you want to match those groups, you need to force it to keep going. One way to do that is just to add `$` to the end of your regular expression:

```
>>> regex = re.search('[A-Za-z ]+(in (?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in (?P<country>[A-z]+))?$', line)
>>> regex.groupdict()
{'country': 'Holland', 'year': '2000'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even tho group is optional it will still match if there.
But the `in` is being consumed before it gets there, so no match on year.

Try this, have to stop just before it gets to `in`

`r"(?:(?!in[ ]\d{4})[A-Za-z ])+(in[ ](?P<year>\d\d\d\d))?\s?(in[ ](?P<country>[A-z]+))?"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsgZku/1) and [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/KsgZku/2)